# How to check the value of cname records

Tags: email, web, cdn, cname, registrar

I'm been trying to integrate my Email service provider with my CDN.  As part of the process the ESP asks to add a CNAME record to your nameserver (here my CDN) with a specific value.

eg 
Record Type : CNAME
Hostname : email.mydomain.com
Value : esp.org

However even after adding this my ESP doesn't pick it up and so it's fallen in the gap between the ESP adn CDN blaming each other.  Is there a way I can check the CNAME record and get the value returned?  (How is the ESP validating this?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found dig from the command line was the best option (preinstalled in OSX and Linux).

```
$dig mg.somedomain.com                                     

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> mg.somedomain.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 62368
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mg.somedomain.com. IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
mg.somedomain.com. 300 IN   CNAME   mailgun.org.
mailgun.org.        37  IN  A   52.205.109.69
mailgun.org.        37  IN  A   23.20.45.146

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
mailgun.org.        96414   IN  NS  ns-133.awsdns-16.com.
mailgun.org.        96414   IN  NS  ns-1482.awsdns-57.org.
mailgun.org.        96414   IN  NS  ns-1614.awsdns-09.co.uk.
mailgun.org.        96414   IN  NS  ns-586.awsdns-09.net.

;; Query time: 38 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1)
;; WHEN: Fri Nov  4 13:30:24 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 236
```